# git sub..submodules tag synchronization

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am new to git submodules.

I am creating a project that includes other libraries as submodules. Some of them though have submodules on their own.

When I have only one level I can go in the root of the submodule and checkout particular tag. Git identifies that and creates a record. The next time I say update on clean place I have the exact change.

This though does not seem to be the case for sub submodule. And I do not see any easy automatic way to apply a particular tag to all submodules.

Am I asking too much, or I just do not know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make sense for a *sub submodule* or breaks consistency if the first level submodule.

Considering you're working on software - it should only take care of it's direct dependencies and should not bother with the dependencies of your dependencies. If you depend of the version of a *sub submodule* then transform it into a direct dependency / submodule.

**Edit**
Just some commands which might help:

```
git clone <repo> --recursive
```

Will align all submodules and their submodules during the initial clone

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Will do the same, once you're working in a repository.

Cheers

Comment: I would agree with you if git was making sure that all the sub.sub.modules are aligned with the sub.module, but it does not. In fact this is exactly what I am trying to find out how to do.

Comment: In fact even this is not exactly true, I could have a module that works agains more than one version of a sub.module